# NMaximize not finding initial points within simple constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to do an optimization, but Mathematica seems not to be able to find starting coordinates within a simple rectangular region.  When I run this code:

```
NMaximize[
 {
  A + B + X + Y,
  74 < A < 222 &&
   .9 < B < 10 &&
   3.2 < X < 3.6 &&
   3.2*^10 < Y < 3.6*^10
  },
 {A, B, X, Y},
 Method -> {"NelderMead", "RandomSeed" -> RandomInteger[{0, 10000}]},
 MaxIterations -> 10000
 ]
```

Mathematica prints the message

> NMaximize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {}.    {-[Infinity], {A -> Indeterminate, B -> Indeterminate, X -> Indeterminate, Y -> Indeterminate}}

The bizarre thing is that that is the simplest working example I've been able to make: when I remove a variable or even just change the numbers to have fewer digits (like replacing .9 with 0), `NMaximize` works.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Indeed, that's weird. I tend to classify this as bug. Anyone else, too?

Comment: Does this bug happen when you run the code?

Comment: Yes. It does. Weird indeed.

Comment: Works for `3.2*^9 < Y < 3.6*^9` and  `1*^10 < Y < 3.6*^10` and fails for `2*^10 < Y < 3.6*^10`